# VS Code: How to convert snippet placeholder from camelCase to SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'd like to create a VS Code snippet for creating redux reducers.

I would like to have a snippet with placeholder that expects camelCase and then transform a matching placeholder to SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE.

Here's my attempted snippet, which is not working:

```
"test": {
    "prefix": "test",
    "body": "${1} -> ${1/([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/${1:/upcase}_/g}"
},
```

Which produces a non-desired result:

```
changeNetworkStatus -> changE_NetworK_Status
```

### Desired Flow

1. type `test` (name of snippet)
2. hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to load the snippet.
3. type `changeNetworkStatus` to result in:

   ```
   changeNetworkStatus -> changeNetworkStatus
   ```
4. hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to get expected result of:

   ```
   changeNetworkStatus -> CHANGE_NETWORK_STATUS
   ```

How can I change my snippet code to get the desired result?

[Here's a related solution which requires a different flow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119284/snippet-variable-in-few-places-with-modificatin-for-some-of-them/49454567#49454567)

Comment: Which version of VS Code? Does provided answer work for you?

Comment: @Braca - Version 1.25.1 - Yes provided answer does work. Why? Do you have better solution?

Comment: No, the answer is great. I've had a problem, it worked 50% of the time (same version). Solved by pressing 'esc'. Just wondering if that's  the standard behavior  or I have some conflicting settings.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by having to press 'esc' - using a prefix that is unique, like "_sc" might fix that for you.  The problem with "test" in the answer is that that could easily show up in your own intellisense suggestions from something else and hitting "tab" would autocomplete that other thing if you weren't careful to select this actual snippet for expansion.  That is why I would always use a prefix that isn't so common as "test".

Comment: @Mark The default setting is: `"javascript.nameSuggestions": true` , when set to 'false' the problem is gone

Comment: Yes, because intellisense then does not pick up random words from the file that fuzzy match the prefix.  Or use a unique prefix.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are starting with a non-camelCase input and want to get to SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67008397/836330.  The method there can handle input with spaces and hyphens.

---

Update: **Keybinding version**:

VScode is adding the `editor.action.transformToSnakecase` in v1.53 so the requested operation can be done easier without having to figure out the neccessary regex to make it work as shown in the previous answer.  And because some people might find this question looking for snake case (snake-case) information.

What I show now is NOT a snippet however.  You just type your text and then trigger the keybinding.  The keybinding itself fires a macro extension command from the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension.  In `keybindings.json`:

```
      {
        "key": "alt+3",                        // whatever keybinding you wish
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
          "sequence": [
            "cursorWordLeftSelect",            // select word you just typed
            "editor.action.transformToSnakecase",
            "editor.action.transformToUppercase",
            // "cursorLineEnd"                   // if you want this
          ]
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
      },
```

Demo of keybinding version:

[image: snake case demo]

---

**Snippet version**:

```
"camelCaseModify": {
    "prefix": "test",       
    "body": [
       
       //  first inefficient try, works for up to three words
       //  "${1} -> ${1/^([a-z]*)([A-Z])([a-z]+)*([A-Z])*([a-z]+)*/${1:/upcase}_$2${3:/upcase}${4:+_}$4${5:/upcase}/g}"

       "${1} -> ${1/([a-z]*)(([A-Z])+([a-z]+))?/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}$3${4:/upcase}/g}",

// here is an especially gnarly version to handle edge cases like 'thisISABCTest' and trailing _'s
       "${1} -> ${1/([a-z]+)(?=[A-Z])|([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|([A-Z][a-z]+)(?=$)|([A-Z][a-z]+)|([a-z]+)(?=$)/${1:/upcase}${1:+_}$2${2:+_}${3:/upcase}${4:/upcase}${4:+_}${5:/upcase}/g}"
        
    ],
    "description": "underscore separators"
},
```

This works with any number of camelCase words, from one to infinity...

The  `${2:+_}` means "if there is a capture group 2 then append an underscore."  If there isn't a second word/capture group then groups 3 and 4 will be empty anyway because they are within capture group 2. Capture Group 2 is always the next Word (that starts with one capital and followed by at least one small letter).

for example, using `changeNetworkStatus`:

```
Match 1

Full match    0-13    `changeNetwork`
Group 1.      0-6     `change`
Group 2.      6-13    `Network`
Group 3.      6-7     `N`
Group 4.      7-13    `etwork`

Match 2

Full match    13-19    `Status`
Group 1.      13-13     ``
Group 2.      13-19     `Status`
Group 3.      13-14     `S`
Group 4.      14-19     `tatus`

Match 3

Full match    19-19    ``
Group 1.      19-19    ``
```

Sample Output:

```
abcd -> ABCD
twoFish -> TWO_FISH
threeFishMore -> THREE_FISH_MORE
fourFishOneMore -> FOUR_FISH_ONE_MORE
fiveFishTwoMoreFish -> FIVE_FISH_TWO_MORE_FISH
sixFishEelsSnakesDogsCatsMiceRatsClocksRocks -> SIX_FISH_EELS_SNAKES_DOGS_CATS_MICE_RATS_CLOCKS_ROCKS
```

Using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) really helps to visualize what is going on!

Comment: If anyone is struggling to get this working, it doesn't run on type but runs on tab.

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work for "AbcDef" -> "abc_def" since the first item cannot serve as a guard. Couldn't come up with a proper trick for this one (always end up with "abc_def_" since I cannot differentiate the end of the string).

Comment: @Qortex which version (keybinding/macro or snippet) are you interested in?  I have a solution for both for the form `AbcDef` `AbcDefGhiJkl...`.  Post a new question and link here so I see it.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, here is the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566628/how-to-convert-snippet-placeholder-from-camelcase-to-snake-case

Comment: there's an edge case where this doesn't work: `thisIsATest` becomes `THIS_IS_TEST` instead of `THIS_IS_A_TEST`.  Capital letters preceeded by a lowercase letter should get an underscore inserted before them, as well as capital letters followed by a lowercase letter.

Comment: @Andy I edited the answer with a snippet version which I believe handles those edge cases - it is significantly more complicated.  In any case, the keybinding macro version does hande your edge case as it was.