# VSCode snippet convert first uppercase letter to lowercase

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I would like to convert the **first uppercased** letter in a VSCode Dart snippet to a **lowercased** one.

Example:

```
MyClassIWroteInMySnippet -> myClassIWroteInMySnippet
```

During my search, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277998/vs-code-how-to-convert-snippet-placeholder-from-camelcase-to-screaming-snake-ca/51394767#51394767) which demonstrate how to convert a **camelCase** String to **UPPER_CASED_STRING** but I don't achieve to pick **the first character** (in uppercase) and then transform it to lowercase...

Any help would be very **appreciated** !

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Here is my current snippet

```
"Mock a service using Mockito": {
    "prefix": "testMockitoService",
    "body": [
        "class _${1}Mock extends Mock implements ${1} {}",
        "",
        "final ${1} = _${1}Mock();", // Here I want to "${1}" be camelCased when I finish to write my class
    ],
    "description": "Mock a service using Mockito"
},
```

So If I insert my snippet, and write "MyClass", I want to display in my code

```
class _MyClassMock extends Mock implements MyClass {}

final myClass = _MyClassMock();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your clarification in the question, try this:

```
  "Mock a service using Mockito": {
    "prefix": "testMockitoService",
    "body": [
        "class _${1}Mock extends Mock implements ${1} {}",
        "",
        "final ${1/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/} = _${1}Mock();",
    ],
    "description": "Mock a service using Mockito"
  },
```

---

`${1/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/}` puts the first letter into capture group 1 and the rest into capture group 2.  Then that first letter is down-cased and the second group appended to that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exactly what I search. I want to write my UPPERCASE word and when it's done, then convert the first letter to downcase. I edited my post for more info. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You are awesome ! This is perfectly what I'm looking for thanks again !