# Visual Studio snippet - How to convert first letter to lowercase

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

In Visual Studio, I would like to update the fullprop snipped to automatically convert the field name according to property name:  (and so only enter "property name" & "type")

```
public string MyTest
{
    get => _myTest;
    set
    {
        if (_myTest == value) return;
        _myTest = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
private string _myTest;
```

I can't find a way to convert `MyProperty` in `myProperty`.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64246642/vscode-snippet-convert-first-uppercase-letter-to-lowercase) topic which seems to work with VSCode but it doesn't work in Visual Studio. Snippet in VSCode seems to be different from Visual Studio as `$1$` works in visual studio but `${1}` doesn't work. So is there an equivalent way in Visual Studio ?

Thanks for your help !